# Django UserCreationForm for custom model is outputting 3 password fields password, password1, and password2

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

Ok, so I have a user registration form based on AbstractUser that replaces the Django model in my settings.py, the model only adds a couple of fields I needed for info on the users, when I tested the registration form the user did not get created, I debugged and found that both last login and date joined where required so I set them as hidden inputs with value of

```
{% now "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" %}
```

that solved the first two errors however there is a third error that says the field password is required, that is my form is asking me for, password, password1, and password2

I would really appreciatte your help!

This is my views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.is_active = True
            new_user.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Usuario')
            new_user.groups.add(group)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

   else:
       form = UserRegisterForm()

   return render_to_response('register.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

This is my model

```
class SiteUser(AbstractUser):
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes_usuarios', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes_usuarios/thumbs', blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', blank=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteUser

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            # Not sure why UserCreationForm doesn't do this in the first place,
            # or at least test to see if _meta.model is there and if not use User...
            self._meta.model._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except self._meta.model.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
```

And here is my template

```
<div class="content">
    <form class="registration" method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="date_joined" value="{% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %}">
        <input type="hidden" name="last_login" value="{% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %}">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group {% if form.username.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.username.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.username.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group {% if form.first_name.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.first_name.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.first_name.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group {% if form.last_name.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.last_name.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.last_name.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.last_name.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group {% if form.email.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.email.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.email.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group {% if form.password1.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.password1.label }}</label>
                <input type="password" id="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.password1.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.password1.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group {% if form.password2.errors %}has-error{% endif %} col-xs-6">
                <label for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}"
                       class="control-label">{{ form.password2.label }}</label>
                <input type="password" id="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}" class="form-control"
                       name="{{ form.password2.html_name }}">
                {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
                    <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but, if you still have the chance to switch technologies, I'd recommend you look at [django-registration](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration) and [crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) to make this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: @Garry Thank you for your suggestion!! I thought about that however I wasn't sure if django-registration would require too much tweeking to work with a custom user model, is it the case, I can't seem to find official documentation about that

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using UserCreationForm it requires all the fields to validate and save the form, why not try **ModelForm** instead.

Refer this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/
Refer this