# why I get three password fields when I define my custom registration form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-registration

I am defining a custom registration form that includes email Field in it. Here is the code:

`forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #define fields
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password','password2')

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

`views.py:`

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        #form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        form=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/register_success")

    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    #args['form']=UserCreationForm()
    args['form']=MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,"register.html",args)
```

`templates/register.html:`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type="submit" value="register"/>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see from the attached screenshot, I get three `password Fields`. why is that?
A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830126/django-usercreationform-for-custom-model-is-outputting-3-password-fields-passwor), but no solution is provided.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because you are defining a `new password field`. your `fields` in `class Meta` should be as follows:

```
class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password1','password2')
```

In this case, you are inheriting the fields from `UserCreationForm`.